# Mail Embed Image timing out laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Using laravel 5.8 . Have the below img tag in the mail blade template .  logo image exists in the directory. Laravel code times out when it encounters the below statement.   Logo seems to be not appearing in the email if i have the url directly in the image tag.
Is there any time out settings i need to do in laravel 5.8 for the embed to work? When i test the below in my local system it works.  Integrated with aws ses.

embed(url('/assets/img/logo/logo-2.png')) }}">

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Using public_url() function fixed the issue.  Also keep logo size minimal for email.